# Choosing a transistor/mosfet in order to drive Peltier element from a RPI zero

Tags: pi-zero-w, mosfet

I just found these two ([1](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/peltier-modules/1743114/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E5B5C707B4C7D5C707B4E647D2D2C2F255C2E5D2B2426706F3D31333326736E3D592673723D2673743D4B4559574F52445F53494E474C455F414C5048415F4E554D455249432673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D4D474D3235302D33312D31302D3136267374613D4D474D3235302D33312D31302D313626&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D),[2](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/peltier-modules/1743116/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E5B5C707B4C7D5C707B4E647D2D2C2F255C2E5D2B2426706F3D31333326736E3D592673723D2673743D4B4559574F52445F53494E474C455F414C5048415F4E554D455249432673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D4D474D3235302D34392D31302D3136267374613D4D474D3235302D34392D31302D313626&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D)) low power consuming Peltier elements that I would like to include them to my project. What I'm planning to do is to drive them until to reach some specific temperature e.g 60-90 Celcius (using some kind of PID).

Since they consume so little power, I thought that they might be able to be controlled with a simple transistor/MOSFET but I don't really know how exactly to choose the proper one.

Any idea on which one to choose? Also, I would be interested (if one has time to write it down) to see the whole pipeline you follow to choose a proper one.

Thanks.

Comment: This will probably get flagged as it has nothing to do with raspberry pi. A better place to ask might be https://electronics.stackexchange.com/   Or google "Drive a 1A load with Mosfet" and you will find examples. Just make sure what ever MOSFET you select can be driven with 3.3V

Comment: @ChadG Suggesting users to cross-post is only going to disappoint them more when their question will get closed twice.

Comment: @J.Doe If your goal is to *heat something up*, you should really use a power resistor, not a Peltier element, unless by "reach some specific temperature e.g 60-90 Celcius" means you want to cool something down to 90°C.